# Output K-Means to CSV with SciKit Learn - give cluster names

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have the below scikit learn script which outputs a nice chart (below) with each of the clusters.

I have a couple of questions:
- How can I export this to CSV - with a cluster name or ID?
- How can I name the clusters?
- How can I make sure the clusters are always named the same thing? For example, I want to call the top right segment 'high spenders' how do I so that where it will always be correct?

Thanks!

[image]

```
#import the required libraries
# - matplotlib is a charting library
# - Seaborn builds on top of Matplotlib and introduces additional plot types. It also makes your traditional Matplotlib plots look a bit prettier.
# - Numpy is numerical Python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
#Generate sample data, with distinct clusters for testing
#n_samples = the number of datapoints, equally split across each clusters
#centers = The number of centers to generate (number of clusters) - a center is the arithmetic mean of all the points belonging to the cluster.
#cluster_std = the standard deviation of the clusters - a quantity expressing by how much the members of a group differ from the mean value for the group (how tight is the cluster going to be)
#random_state = controls the random number generator being used.  If you don't mention the random_state in the code, then whenever you execute your code a new random value is generated and the train and test datasets would have different values each time. However, if you use a particular value for random_state(random_state = 1 or any other value) everytime the result will be same,i.e, same values in train and test datasets.
#make_blobs generates "isotropic Gaussian blobs" - X is a numpy array with two columns which contain the (x, y) Gaussian coordinates of these points, whereas y contains the list of categories for each.
#X, y = simply means that the output of make_blobs() has two elements, that are assigned to X and y.
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=4,
                       cluster_std=0.50, random_state=0)
#X now looks like this - column zero becomes the X axis, column1 becomes the Y axis
array([[ 1.85219907,  1.10411295],
       [-1.27582283,  7.76448722],
       [ 1.0060939 ,  4.43642592],
       [-1.20998253,  7.83203579],
       [ 1.92461484,  1.06347673],
       [ 2.28565919,  0.79166208],
       [-1.57379043,  2.69773813],
       [ 1.04917913,  4.31668562],
       [-1.07436851,  7.93489945],
       [-1.15872975,  7.97295642]
#The below statement, will enable us to visualise matplotlib charts, even in ipython
#Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX
#Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
%pylab
#plot the chart
#s = the sizer of the points.
#X[:, 0] is the numpy coordinates way of selecting every row entry for column 0 - i.e. a single column from the numpy array.
#X[:, 1] is the numpy coordinates way of selecting every row entry for column 1 - i.e. a single column from the numpy array.
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=50);
#now, I am definining that I want to find 4 clusters within the data. The general rule I follow is, I will have 7 times less clusters than datapoints.
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
#build the model, based on X with the number of clusters defined above
kmeans.fit(X)
#now we're going to find clusters in the randomly generated dataset
predict = kmeans.predict(X)
#now we can plot the prediction
#c = colour, which is based on the predict variable we defined above
#s = the size of the plots
#X[:, 0] is the numpy coordinates way of selecting every row entry for column 0 - i.e. a single column from the numpy array.
#X[:, 1] is the numpy coordinates way of selecting every row entry for column 1 - i.e. a single column from the numpy array.
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=predict, s=50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code the following worked for me. You can certainly stay with numpy for storing the CSV but I simply prefer pandas. The sorting line *should* give you the same results everytime you run the code. However, since the initliazation of the clusters can have an impact I would also set a seed in your code, e.g. `np.random.seed(42)` and call the kmeans function with the random_state parameter, e.g. `kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=42)`

```
# transform to dataframe
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df.columns = ["var1", "var2"]
df["cluster"] = predict
colors = sns.color_palette()[0:4]
df = df.sort_values("cluster")

# check plot
sns.scatterplot(df["var1"], df["var2"], hue=df["cluster"], palette=colors)
plt.show()

# define rename schema
mynames = {"0": "center_left", "1": "top_left", "2": "bot_right", "3": "center"}
df["cluster_name"] = [mynames[str(i)] for i in df.cluster]

# plot again to verify order
sns.scatterplot(df["var1"], df["var2"], hue=df["cluster_name"], 
                palette=colors)
sns.despine()
plt.show()

# save dataframe as CSV
df.to_csv("myoutput.csv")
```

The first plot looks like this:

[image]

The second plot looks like this:

[image]

The CSV will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - when I run the same code, I get a different colour mapping & hence the order is wrong. The top left label on mine is actually middle right, which suggests, it changes?

Comment: I did not set a seed in my code. Adapt your naming once you have set a seed.